# GKMatchmakerViewController - how to detect pressing "Play Now"

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gkmatchmaker

Is there a way to detect when "Play Now" button in GKMatchmakerViewController pressed?

All I can find in ref docs are:

– matchmakerViewController:didFindMatch:

– matchmakerViewController:didFindPlayers:

– matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:

– matchmakerViewController:didFailWithError:

– matchmakerViewController:didReceiveAcceptFromHostedPlayer:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the view controller doesn't invoke a delegate method for that event. What do you intend to do with that information? Game Center's matchmaking is largely opaque, so as far as I know there's no way to influence the matchmaking process at that point.